# Using the core of a toroidal inductor as the core for a toroidal transformer?

Tags: transformer

As the title says, I have quite a few toroidal cores that I have gathered over time, and would like to reuse them, do they also work as transformer cores?

Comment: Yes, they should work. But maybe not very well, as the material might be not optimized for the application.

Comment: Wow, that was quick! Thank you, I didn't want to waist the time winding one, then find out it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

Powdered iron cores designed for EMI mitigation are lossy and may not work that well. If there are markings on the core you may be able to look up the material characteristics (and, of course, you can measure the core dimensions). If there is a standard color code for cores I'm not aware of it.

You can test the Al by winding some turns on the core and measure the resulting inductance. Divide the uH you read by the square of the number of turns you added to get the Al value.

Comment: I remember seeing someone try this a long time ago with an EMI core. Wanted to use it for a power application. The core glowed red-hot before it failed.

Comment: @rdtsc I guess it could be a feature- use it as an RF-fed heater.

Comment: Tip: for more precision, thread a single wire through the center of 10 identical toroid cores, forming 10 series-connected 1-turn inductors -- then directly measure 10x the mean Al value. (Since a ferrite toroid contains most of its magnetic flux inside the toroid, there's negligible coupling; so when connected in series the inductances simply add.)

Comment: Well,I tried it, my house tripped. I guess I need to add more windings.

Comment: Generally ferrites are not effective core materials for mains transformers. Please do not kill yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, any type of core that is suitable for a low-loss inductor will be suitable as a transformer (in one application or another). If they are small cores don't expect to be able to fit on the number of turns to make an AC power transformer. That sort of application will need several thousand turns for a small core whether ferrite or iron.

Also don't expect some cores to work as 100 MHz transformers in radios - specialist cores are needed for this.

Answer (score 0):

A transformer is generally two inductors whose magnetic fields are coupled together.

A transformer does NOT need a magnetic core. Radio frequency circuits often use transformers with **air cores**, but the mutual coupling is still there by proximity.

Transformer design is of course a detailed section of science and an entire career can be made in transformer design.

There is a big difference between hobbyist use and professional design.

If you knew the original use of the inductor, that could lead you to decide whether the core material was suitable for your needs (hobbyist). Otherwise, in professional work you would need to know the specifications of the core material.

To make a silly comparison,  a steel nail (lump of steel used for attaching wood products) can be used as a core for a transformer (in very peculiar circumstances).

My main intent here is to illustrate that anything from air to a nail could be used as a core for a transformer. Of course I understood your question to be,  would the inductor core be an **effective** core for a transformer.

Comment: Thank you, very informative, it was purely just to experiment, as I have lots of them.

Comment: I suspected "hobbyist" by your mention of having collected many of them and wanting to re-use the cores. Part of the fun is doing it anyway, and seeing the results (as compared to ideal transformer).

Comment: Transformer cores are usually not gapped.  Inductor cores tend to be gapped.  Toroid cores of power inductors have what's called "distributed gap", which you can't see.  I would advise to buy the type of core that you want for the transformer.  It will have a datasheet, you will know exactly what material it is.  That's more reliable than cannibalizing.

Comment: How many turns would be needed to safely use 240V as a input voltage? its a really small, about an inch across, and a cm or so thick.

Comment: @alextix  I can't say with the limited information, and also depends upon how much current you will allow the transformer to draw from mains when unloaded secondary. Take primary inductors impedance (2* PI * L* Frequency = XL) Then primary current would be (240v / XL). Yes, a transformer primary is merely an inductor when there is no secondary loading. That is why transformers get warm even when no secondary load.