# Can a "distributed gap" powdered-iron or ferrite toroidal core be used for a flyback converter's coupled inductor?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, inductor, flyback

As just about all of us who deal with switching power supplies know, flyback converter designs use an air-gapped coupled inductor instead of a transformer.  Typically, this gap is an explicit gap in an E-I type core.

Nick Alexeev points out in a comment, though, that:

> Transformer cores are usually not gapped. Inductor cores tend to be gapped. Toroid cores of power inductors have what's called "distributed gap", which you can't see.

Can a "distributed gap" toroid core yield satisfactory results when used for a flyback converter's coupled inductor, or will it cause undesirable effects when used instead of an E-I core with an explicit gap?

Comment: distributed gaps fringe less .  They are good on planars if only somebody would make the appropriate ferrite parts .+ 1

Answer (score 6):

I believe the type of "distributed gap" that Nick Alexeev comment refers to in [This question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/using-the-core-of-a-toroidal-inductor-as-the-core-for-a-toroidal-transformer/208483?noredirect=1#comment440931_208483) , is regarding a "Powder Core" material.

Powder Iron Core material is, loosely speaking, granules of Iron emulsified in a binder (the stuff that holds the material together), similar to an epoxy. So the iron granules literally have a physical separation from each other by virtue of the binder material. This is the "distributed gap". Literally a large number of small gaps.

With laminated iron cores, the gap is explicit and at one section of the core.

Ferrite cores for the most part do not have a distributed gap.

Providing a gap is a technique to avoid saturation of the core material.

> For power module designs, the inductor's saturation level is critical. Saturation level is typically defined as the dc current level at which the device's inductance declines to 75% to 80% of its nominal inductance. The dc current can saturate the inductor quickly if an air gap is not introduced into the core's magnetic path. Powdered iron materials have an inherent air gap that is distributed throughout the core, which gives them a soft saturation curve. Ferrite material must have an air gap physically inserted or ground between the mating surfaces of the core halves.
>   [Taken from [Power Electronics](http://powerelectronics.com/passive-components/ferrite-out-better-core-materials-your-pol-design) ]

Since the "distributed gap" of a powdered iron core material is literally a gap, yes, a powdered iron core can be used as if the core were literally gapped.

Powder Iron cores are lossy, and that should definitely be a consideration. In most cases the core loss will be too high to use in most high frequency transformer applications. But the distributed gap is still valid as a gap. The losses in powdered iron core material may make it an unsuitable candidate, but that would depend upon the application.

Answer (score 2):

> As just about all of us who deal with switching power supplies know,
>   flyback converter designs use an air-gapped coupled inductor instead
>   of a transformer.

This is untrue. To avoid saturation of the core, in some circumstances, a gap is used but, a gap isn't a pre-requisite for a flyback converter and a gap isn't a pre-requisite for an inductor.

For a small gap, the effective permeability of a core is this: -

\$\mu_e = \dfrac{\mu_i}{1+\dfrac{\mu_i\cdot gap}{l_e}}\$

- Where \$\mu_e\$ is the effective permeability of the core (after gapping),
- \$\mu_i\$ is the initial permeability of the core prior to gapping
- and \$l_e\$ is the effective length of the core (green dotted line): -

[image]

A "small gap" is specified for the formula's accuracy because (to quote Ferroxcube): -

> This simple formula is a good approximation only for small air-gaps.
>   For longer air-gaps some flux will cross the gap outside its normal
>   area (stray flux) causing an increase of the effective permeability.

For a "distributed gap" toroid core, the formula applies because all the "gaps" are really, really small.

Comment: Though an air-gap is not a prerequisite for an inductor, one is typically used because it increases its energy storage. The permeability of the gap is much lower than the core, so most of the stored magnetic energy is in the gap.  The gap also helps stabilize the inductance, since the core properties often vary with temperature, flux levels, etc.

Comment: @user28910 you might want to consider what you are saying - applying an air gap reduces inductance and therefore, the energy that can be stored (for a given current) is reduced. To recover that inductance (say if permeability quartered) requires twice the turns and, for the same current applied, the ampere turns are doubled and this can lead to greater saturation of the core. So, what are you saying?

Comment: it's true that an air gap will reduce the permeance of the magnetic circuit and therefore the inductance. But that doesn't mean energy storage capability is reduced. Using your example: an air-gap is introduced, the permeance is quartered so the number of turns is doubled to maintain the inductance.  But now, at same current, the flux density is one-half of that of the ungapped core (flux = permeance x amp-turns). To operate the gapped core at the same flux density (and proximity to saturation) requires twice the current, quadrupling the stored energy.

Comment: @user28910 yes you are right about that - I got muddles up thinking about it (it happens now and then!).